# Same Stored Procedure is taking different time to execute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I am facing an issue with one of stored procedure in Sql Server.

In one database the Stored procedure is taking around 27 minutes 04 seconds to execute one XML. Basic functionality of this SP is to insert/update data in different tables taking XML input. The same SP is taking only one and half minutes to execute the same XML in different databases.

We have created a backup of the database one month back, when I executed the SP with same input in Backup database it also took 1 minute 04 sec. So can anyone please tell me what should I check between the current and backuped database because the issue is really strange and it seems in my current database something has been changed recently wothout my knowledge.

Comment: Are the indexes okay on the tables involved? Are there other users accessing the first database but not the backup database?

Comment: Take a look at the execution plans for the procedures, are they same or different?

Answer (score 6):

- Statistics are up to date? `exec sp_updatestats 'RESAMPLE'`
- Amount of data in affected tables is slightly different?
- Rebuild indexes `exec sp_msforeachtable 'alter index all on ? rebuild'`
- There are new indexes on affected tables?

Update:

- There is different load over there databases/tables?
- Any other maintenance tasks?

PS: All proposed code is for Sql Server